# How to cache data in server using files

Tags: java, caching, spring-mvc

I am writing an application in which I need to store huge amount of data in DB and cache the same. When ever client requests comes, server needs to fetch the data  from cache and return the same.

Here is how am doing it:
(Offline Process)
1. We have a spring batch application which gets the json file (around 6MB in size). 
2. Reads each object and store it in DB.
3. Approximately 17K records is being stored in DB.

(Online Process)
4. when ever request comes to the server (web app - Spring web MVC), the app gets the data from the DB and returns response.

I am planing to avoid DB storage here. Instead of using DB, can I add the file in a file server and cache the data present in the file whenever the server is started?

Let me know if there is any existing methodology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching won't be a replacement for persistence. you can store data in a file system instead of a db but the whole point of having a db in the first place is that data storage and retrieval is much faster in a db than in a normal file system because of better structuring of data and indexing (along with the huge advantage of ease of querying to get data). you can always dump your data in a db in huge file formats (not recommended)

For caching, you can use memcached or redis. Note that caching is not 100% reliable. You can configure the cache to specify a time after which cache should be cleared. You also need to keep updating the cache data whenever you create/update some data in your db. If your cache gets full, normally least-used resources will be cleared from the cache first to accommodate new data.

The ideal solution for you would be to use a scalable (read non-relational) db with a caching layer like memcache. On a side note, it is extremely easy to use memcache with spring (I haven't used redis in an application yet). Since you mention json data formats, take a look at [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) for persistence.